Normal Cones on a Circular Arc
Let $C = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, y \geq 0, y \leq x\}.$  I wish to determine the normal cone $N_C(x_0, y_0)$, for any $(x_0, y_0)$ on the boundary of $C$.
There are six cases to consider:

$(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$
$(x_0, y_0) = (1, 0)$
$(x_0, y_0) = (1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$
$(x_0, y_0) = (x, 0),$ where $0 < x < 1$
$(x_0, y_0) = (x, x),$ where $0 < x < 1/\sqrt{2}$
$(x_0, y_0)$ is on the circular arc from $(0, 0)$ to $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$.

I have so far determined the normal cones to 4. and 5. to be
\begin{align*}
N_C(x_0, y_0) = \{(0, v_2): v_2 \leq 0\} = \{\lambda (0, -1): \lambda \geq 0\}. 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
N_C(x_0, y_0) = \{(v_1, -v_1): v_1 \leq 0\} = \{\lambda(-1, 1): \lambda \geq 0\},
\end{align*}
in the following way: For 4., Suppose $(v_1, v_2)$ satisfies, for any $(x, y) \in C$
$$(v_1, v_2) \cdot (x-x_0, y-x_0) \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow v_1(x-x_0)+v_2(y-x_0) \leq 0.$$
Then, it is clear $v_2 \leq 0$. If $v_1 = 0$, the equation is at once satisfied; if $v_1 \neq 0$, say $v_1 >0$, then we can find $(x', 0) \in C$, $x'> x_0$ for which $v_1(x-x_0)+v_2(y-x_0) < 0$.
However, I am struggling to find the normal cones to all others. How might this be done?

Did you draw a little picture of $C$?

Here are some hints (some work is required to establish the equivalences. You should dray a little diagram of $C$ to gain some intuition. The equivalences below rely on the fact that $C$ is convex (and closed).
It might help to notice that if $C$ has the form
$C = \operatorname{co} (C_1 \cup \cdots \cup C_m)$ and $x_0 \in C$, then $N_C(x) = \cap_k \{ n | \langle n, x-x_0 \rangle \le 0 \text{ for all } x \in C_k \}$. Note that we can write
$C = \operatorname{co} ( \{ (0,0) \} \cup \{ (\sqrt{1-t^2},t) | t \in [0,{1 \over \sqrt{2}}] \}$.
For 1. $n \in N_C((0,0))$ iff $n_1x_1 +n_2x_2 \le 0$ for all $x \in C$ iff $n_1x_1 +n_2x_2 \le 0$ for all $x=(t,t)$ with $t \ge 0$ and for all $x =(s,0)$ with $s \ge 0$ iff $n_1 \le 0$ and $n_1 + n_2 \le 0$. That is, $N_C((0,0)) = \{ n | n_1 \le 0 \} \cap \{ n | n_1 + n_2 \le 0 \}$.
For 2. $n \in N_C((1,0))$ iff $n_1(x_1-1) +n_2x_2 \le 0$ for all $x \in C$ iff $n_1(x_1-1) +n_2x_2 \le 0$ for all $x=(t,0)$ with $t \in [0,1]$ and for all $x$ satisfying $x_1^2+x_2^2 =1$ with $x_1 \ge x_2 \ge 0$ iff $n_1 \ge 0$ and $n_1 \sqrt{1-t^2} + n_2 t \le 0$ for all $t \in [0,{1 \over \sqrt{2}}]$ iff $n_1 \ge 0$ and $n_2 \le 0$. That is, $N_C((1,0)) = \{ n | n_1 \ge 0, n_2 \le 0 \}$.
